# Не могу число из файла преобразовать в переменную

Tags: python

Надо число которое лежит в текстовом файле преобразовать в переменную для дальнейших действий

Comment: У вас в файле одно число, которое надо присвоить переменной?

Comment: приложи пример файла

Comment: Нужен пример входных данных. А также ваш код.

Answer (score -2):

https://repl.it/repls/HuskyLovelyMaps

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
  x = int(file.read())
  print(x)
```

Comment: А если будет несколько чисел?

Comment: @Стас в вопросе сказано *число из файла*

Comment: если число то не факт что инт, может и флот

Comment: А если число комплексное? Давайте гадать что там на входе

Comment: Можно гадать, а можно дать ответ :)

Comment: Кроме числа в файле может быть эи текст

Comment: @Эникейщик с чего вы взяли?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли,  что там только одно число, да ещё и целое?

Comment: @Эникейщик https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бритва_Оккама

Comment: @Эникейщик если это вы поставили минус, то почему?